# Data Structure for Max/Min value in range

Tags: java, algorithm, graphics

I'm giving a example that mirrors my usecase:

I have a histogram say in the range `[0, 10000]`. I want to efficiently support queries of the type:

```
int j = maxYInXRange(20, 70);
```

Which should return maximum `Y` value in the given `X` Range.

I've come across a Data structure called "Priority Search Tree" used in Computer Graphics but there are no easily understandable resources on this topic.

Comment: you could simply sort the collection you are using and return the item at index 70 if i am not mistaken in your question?

Comment: I think the question is looking for something better than `O(n logn)`

Comment: Maybe use a rank tree where the value in the node holds the maximum of the sub tree? when queried, start form the appropriate nodes in the tree and work all the way up to the LCA. Note that going up from a left or right son will be different results

Comment: I don't see a good reason for using anything beyond a `Map<Integer,Number>` for recording the histogram. Computing minimum or maximum over a range can be done as required. - If you want to be fancy, use a cache of computations (range -> result), which can be used for any request matching or including the previously computed range.

Comment: you could also create a sublist of your given List and insert into a priorityQueue with a reveresed order. Afterwards you just need to poll the first value.

Comment: Yes shapiro, I'm looking for a solution that is atmost log N per query.

Comment: To be more clear, I'm trying to solve the Longest Increasing subsequence problem with this approach. For a given index i, I want to be able to find max sequence length for all j < i and a[j] < a[i]. At the end of each iteration, I want to put a 2-d data point (a[i], sequenceLength(i)) into the said tree

Answer (score 2):

I believe you are trying to solve the [range minimum/maximum query problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Range_minimum_query). There are many ways you can achieve sublinear time per query, if you spend some more time precomputing information at the beginning. There is a good tutorial on several efficient approaches [here](https://www.topcoder.com/community/data-science/data-science-tutorials/range-minimum-query-and-lowest-common-ancestor/).

For example, if your histogram doesn't change, you can answer queries with a sparse table in O(1), with precomputation using O(N log N) time and memory, where N is the number of elements in the histogram. If your histogram changes frequently, a segment tree can be used for O(log N) updates and queries, with O(N) time and memory for a one-time precomputation in the beginning.

Comment: Segment tree would give me maximum among a range of array indices. I want to impose an additional upper bound value on the keys being searched

Comment: Do you mean you want to find the maximum value <= Z in the subarray from X to Y?

Comment: Yes, that was my intended question

Comment: That problem can be solved with a 2D segment tree. However, looking at your comments, it seems like you're trying to solve the LIS problem, which is completely doable with the methods I mentioned (and I'm not sure how it would help you to solve the "new" problem for this purpose). Keep in mind that the segment tree does not have to be over the array - you can do it over the integers from min(a[i]) to max(a[i]). If these values are too large, you can use [coordinate compression](https://www.quora.com/What-is-coordinate-compression).

Answer (score 1):

What about the standard `TreeMap`, using the [subMap(K,boolean,K,boolean)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html#subMap(K,%20boolean,%20K,%20boolean)) method?

```
TreeMap histogram = ...
return histogram.subMap(20,true,70,true).values().stream().max()
```

The lookup of the boundaries will be `O(log n)`. Finding the maximum will be `O(m)`, where m = max-min. I don't think you can find a better data structure unless you precompute everything, which would take `O(n²)` in both computing and storage size, I suppose.

Comment: TreeMap is based on red-black tree whose range(lo, hi) operation takes O(N) time

Answer (score 0):

You could sort the histogram indices by value, highest to lowest. And then, for a given range iterate over it as this:

```
List<Entry> histogramEntries = ... //sorted by value


for(Entry entry: histogramEntries)
  if(range.contains(entry.index))
     return entry.value;
```

This will work faster for larger ranges, since it's more likely to contain one of the higher values that are in the beginning of the list.